# Библиотека EdgeGPT проблема с новой сессией

Tags: python, telebot

У меня есть бот который сделан на EdgeGPT и использовал нецензурную лексику чтобы проверить как бот будет завершать диалог, я делал по этому репозиторию https://github.com/acheong08/EdgeGPT и не понимаю как начать новую сессию чтобы продолжить общение. Если кто то поможет буду благодарен!

Ошибку выдаёт такую:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AleksFOLT\PyCharm\Bing\main.py", line 74, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
  File "C:\Users\AleksFOLT\PyCharm\Bing\newmessengerbot\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1043, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(non_stop=non_stop, interval=interval, timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout=long_polling_timeout,
  File "C:\Users\AleksFOLT\PyCharm\Bing\newmessengerbot\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1118, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\AleksFOLT\PyCharm\Bing\newmessengerbot\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1074, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\AleksFOLT\PyCharm\Bing\newmessengerbot\Lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 147, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "C:\Users\AleksFOLT\PyCharm\Bing\newmessengerbot\Lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 90, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AleksFOLT\PyCharm\Bing\newmessengerbot\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 6788, in _run_middlewares_and_handler
    result = handler['function'](message)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\AleksFOLT\PyCharm\Bing\main.py", line 39, in handle_bing
    response = asyncio.run(chatbot.ask(prompt=user_input, conversation_style=conversation_styles.get(message.chat.id,
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\AleksFOLT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\AleksFOLT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\AleksFOLT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\AleksFOLT\PyCharm\Bing\newmessengerbot\Lib\site-packages\EdgeGPT\EdgeGPT.py", line 116, in ask
    async for final, response in self.chat_hub.ask_stream(
  File "C:\Users\AleksFOLT\PyCharm\Bing\newmessengerbot\Lib\site-packages\EdgeGPT\chathub.py", line 178, in ask_stream
    resp_txt = result_text + response["arguments"][0][
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'adaptiveCards'
```